# Google Cloud Storage .Net Client Library Documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to work with Google Cloud Storage, C# .Net4.5.  The goal will be to manage millions of files that we will upload to Google Cloud Storage, the images will primarily be a backup copy.

I do have some code working using the .Net Client Library using the nuGet:  \Google.Apis.Storage.v1.1.9.0.230\lib\portable-net40+sl50+win+wpa81+wp80\Google.Apis.Storage.v1.dll

What I can't find is any documentation besides what is picked up via Visual Studios' Intellisense.
I'm just looking for the full API and some examples.

Google lists:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/storage/v1

Browse the .Net Reference for Cloud Storage API:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/
  But that takes one to the JSON API overview.

Can anyone kindly point to where I should be looking.

Example:
Listing objects in a bucket.  I can get it to work:
 listRequest = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.ListRequest(storageService, bucketName);

The only documentation on the **ListRequest** class I'm able to find is what is ObjectResource.CS

Where should I be looking?  Or is there just not a lot of help/doc/examples for the .Net Client Library?

Thanks again.
-andy

Comment: Click on the [Classes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html) link at the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you!  Crazy I did not notice the Classes link.

Comment: Adding as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the [Classes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html) link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples) for authenticating, listing buckets and downloading objects.